# How do I assign a component to a Ticket when I first create it with the Jira Rest API?

Tags: json, rest, api, jira

When I try to assign a component to a ticket while I am creating it, it won't assign the component to the ticket. It creates the ticket without the component assigned to it

I try to assign it like this:

```
"components":
    [
       {
          "Name": "Component B"
       }
    ]
```

I was hoping that it would assign the components to the ticket, but it didn't. It doesn't give me an error or anything like that. It just creates the ticket without the components

Comment: Could you try to write the key in lower case?
e.g.
"components" : [ { "name": "Active Directory"} ]

Comment: I just tried it out and it works. I don't know why I didn't try that out yet. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lowercase key for the component helps in this case:

```
"components" : [ { "name": "Active Directory"} ]
```